# FirebaseAuth: getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@9cd3393

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

[image]

Online it says to downgrade the dependencies for Firebase Auth but I have done that and it does not work.

Comment: Please consider copy/paste code directly in the question, thanks.

Comment: Please add error log from your logcat and any error messages returned. Always add logs to questions on StackOverflow to get quicker response. Here's a guide on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please mention previous and current version.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that all your firebase dependencies are using the **same version**. I was also facing the same issue, using stable version `15.0.0` worked well for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your google-services is updated, in build.gradle.project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and try changing your Auth to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

adding the following implementation:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace it
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
<!-- add in Gradel.properties-->
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
<!-- for Activity -->
make sure your activity AppCompatActivity use below imports 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
<!-- add in build.gradel-->
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

in build your build.gradle(Module:app) add this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and in you build.gradle(project:)file copy paste this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
```

and you also have to take care that all your firebase dependencies should be of same version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your developer console and unrestrict all the firebase APIs.
It might have happened because of upgrades to your plan.

Answer (score -1):

the thing is this is not an issue you just need to check your SHA-1 key is updated in your firebase project just update that and check you will not get this problem.

Comment: Would you like to improve readbility by making obvious sentences? Using a little punctuation would do the trick. Also please take the opportunity to explain this specific part, which I do not understand "the thing is this is not an issue".

Answer (score -1):

Use an emulator with Google Play installed.

Comment: This isn't really an answer - better as a comment