# Flutter Firebase Auth Error .createUserWithEmailAndPassword: getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@fb1556c

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

## Preamble

This has been a struggle for a good while now and nothing seems to be working, I have seen answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095074/firebaseauth-getgoogleapiformethod-returned-gms-com-google-firebase-auth-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733720/firebaseauth-getgoogleapiformethod-returned-gms-com-google-firebase-auth-api) but the former was not in flutter and the latter was posted before the [recent changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#authentication) to `firebase_auth` and I guess most importantly the proposed solutions have not worked.

## The Issue

The issue concerns a very very simple initial setup of firebase authentication within flutter. I have set up my firebase project exactly as it suggests [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android) and used [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) and [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview) to set up `firebase_auth`.

The code that is causing the problem is as follows:

```
void _registerTestUser() async {
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: "barry.allen@example.com",
            password: "SuperSecretPassword!");
    print(userCredential.user.email);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('The password provided is too weak.');
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      print('The account already exists for that email.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

When the code is run the error

> I/BiChannelGoogleApi(19546): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@fb1556c

Is returned.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875368/9482067) seems to suggest that the error may well be irrelevant, i.e. the code may work anyway. I put a breakpoint on the line `UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance` and stepped over, it continues to  `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(`, then once stepped over again goes back to the first line and the error is displayed. Stepping over any further breaks out of the function entirely, so the `print(userCredential.user.email);` line is never executed, which would suggest the code isn't working. Additionally the `print(e);` line in the `catch` is not what is outputting this error.

## Other Info

*Pubspec.yaml*

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3 #firebase core flutter sdk
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1 #firebase authorisation
```

*android/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'  // Google Services plugin
}
```

*android/app/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
```

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        // Initialize FlutterFire:
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Check for errors
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Error();
          }

          // Once complete, show your application
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return MyHomePage();
          }

          // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
          return Loading();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Loading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Firebase is loading'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Error extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('There has been an error'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _registerTestUser() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: "barry.allen@example.com",
              password: "SuperSecretPassword!");
      print(userCredential.user.email);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('FlutterFire Test')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Register a test user'),
              onPressed: () => _registerTestUser(),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also this error has appeared a few times, although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913395/9482067) seems to imply it's got nothing to do with my issue and isn't indicative of a problem.

> W/ConnectionTracker(19240): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@fb1556c
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1729)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):1)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):2)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at lq.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):10)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at lc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):2)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):3)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> W/ConnectionTracker(19240):     at ix.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217100@20.42.17 (150700-0):6)

## EDIT

Changing the line `onPressed: () => _registerTestUser(),` in `main.dart` to `onPressed: () {_registerTestUser();}` gives the same result but changes the error slightly, the zzao@fb1556c becomes zzao@ebc85e9.

Comment: Are the email and passwords coming from a textfield input? if yes, why not use a validator instead? Also try to reinstall the google-services.json file from firebase and place it in your project, maybe it was corrupted or something. And finally, after createUserWithEmailAndPassword, add this line code: assert (userCredential != null);

Comment: How are you loading your GoogleService-Info.plist & google-services.json?   Are you using flavors?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so, please mark the one you used as accepted or inform us if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

First of as I can see you have not initialized `firebase` in `main.dart` file correctly.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You missed one statement try again and if still you got problem let me know

Comment: The MyApp() class has a FutureBuilder than ensures Firebase is initialized before the MyHomePage() page is returned.

Comment: And to be clear, initializing firebase in this way in an asynchronous main() yields the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not directly answering your question and being apparently at odds (though not very different to) with the FlutterFire sample code. Here is the code I use to create a user (Firebase_auth Type User) and I don't see your error:

```
User _user = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email,
              password: password,
            )).user;
```

I can then use methods such as `await _user.sendEmailVerification();` and access its properties such as `_user.email` without issue.

Maybe try that instead of the credential.

PS. The issue : `W/ConnectionTracker(19240): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:`
you refer to is being tracked here and I don't believe it is related to your code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issue-638324848

It has several variations of exception code but they are all related.

***Update***
I also believe that @amit kumar is almost correct, you are running `FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;` before `Firebase.initializeApp();`. You need to make sure your future completes before you instantiate FirebaseAuth, I believe. Probably makes my changed code above irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
  void _registerTestUser() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: "barry.allen@example.com",
              password: "SuperSecretPassword!")
          .then((userCredential) => print(userCredential.user.email));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Also consider using User instead of UserCredential:

```
  void _registerTestUser() async {
    try {
      final User user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: "barry.allen@example.com",
                  password: "SuperSecretPassword!"))
          .user;

      print(user.email);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

        registerUser()async{
        _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
         email:"barry.allen@example.com",
         password: "SuperSecretPassword!",
        ).then((result){
User user = result.user;
}).catchError((e) {
          print(e);
        });
    }
```